# Sublime Text 3で設定やパッケージを他のPCに移行したい

Tags: sublimetext

職場や、自宅、ノートPCなど、複数のPCにSublime Text3をインストールして同じ環境にしたいと思っています。１台ずつ手動設定したり、パッケージをインストールするのではなく、１台のPCに構築した設定、パッケージを他のPCに簡単に移行する方法はないでしょうか？

vimではプラグインのインストールにVundlerやneobundleを使っていれば、.vimrcのみ他のPCにコピーすれば、設定の移行が済みますし、プラグインのインストールもコマンドを１回実行するだけで済みます。

Sublime Text3でも同様に、設定ファイルやインストール済みパッケージ一覧をエクスポート／インポートできたりすると良いのですが...

Answer (score 1):

端的に申し上げますと、`Packages/User/`を同期すれば、すべてのSublimeTextの環境を同期することができます。

SublimeTextのパッケージマネージャとして有名なPackage Controlは、インストールしたプラグインを同期する機能を持っています。同期の仕方は下記URLに記載されていますが、ここでは`Packages/User/`を同期することを要求されています。
https://packagecontrol.io/docs/syncing
私はGitを使って同期しています。この場合、いくつか指定されたファイルを.gitignoreに入れておく必要はありますが、後は`Packages/User/`を同期してくれれば、足りないプラグインを自動的にインストール/アップデートしてくれます。

また、プラグイン以外で個人的にSublimeTextに設定を施した場合についても、個人設定ファイルは普通`Packages/User/`に保存されます。

従って、`Packages/User/`を同期すれば、すべての設定が同期されることになります。

Comment: 同期するにあたって、Package Controlだけは手動でインストールしなければならないことを追記しておきます。https://packagecontrol.io/installation